# Ajax no envia el valor del dato a php

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un parámetro que envío a una función javascript, cuando hago un alert de dicho parámetro me muestra su valor, ahí todo correcto. El problema es que ese parámetro lo quiero enviar por Ajax a un archivo php, pero creo que no lo esta haciendo bien porque con ese valor hago una consulta sql y cargar un select pero no hace nada.

El valor del select se lo envio a la funcion asi:

`<select id="tipo" onchange="cargarCategoria(this.value)">`

**Código AJAX**

```
function cargarCategoria(dato)
{
    alert(dato)//Me muestra su valor correctamente
    $.ajax({
        data: dato, //Esto es lo que envio a php, que es un elemento de un select
        type: "POST",
        url: '../consultas/consultarCategoria.php',
        success: function(resp){
            $('#categoria').html(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

**Código PHP**

```
 $valor = $_POST["dato"];
  echo '<script>alert ("DATO: '.$valor.'");</script>';

  $tipo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['dato']);

  $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT categoria FROM formacion WHERE tipo = ".$tipo;
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

  while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo '<option value="'.$fila["categoria"].'">'.$fila["categoria"].'</option>';
  }
```

Como puedo saber si le estoy enviando por ajax bien la variable y como puedo tratarlo en PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que la variable "dato" no existe en PHP.  La solucion seria crear esa variable en json/javascript y mandarla a PHP asi:

```
function cargarCategoria(dato)
{
    alert(dato)//Me muestra su valor correctamente
    $.ajax({
        data: {"dato": dato}, //Esto es lo que envio a php, que es un elemento de un select
        type: "POST",
        url: '../consultas/consultarCategoria.php',
        success: function(resp){
            $('#categoria').html(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Vale de acuerdo, pero no me muestra `$valor = $_POST["dato"];
  echo '<script>alert ("DATO: '.$valor.'");</script>';`

Comment: Debería aparecerme un alert con el valor del dato ?

Comment: Ya lo solucione, estaba mal mi ruta en url

Comment: Que bueno, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar los parametros via Ajax, debes crear primero un arreglo:

```
var Parametros = {
'dato' : dato
}

$.ajax({
        data: Parametros, //Esto es lo que envio a php, que es un elemento de un select
        type: "POST",
        url: '../consultas/consultarCategoria.php',
        success: function(resp){
            $('#categoria').html(resp);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que mandas entre comillas es el nombre de la variable y lo otro el valor

Este es un ejemplo:

```
data: {"dato": dato},

var nombre="Jose";
var apellido="Garcia";
data: {"Nombre":nombre,
       "Apellido":apellido},
```

y en el **PHP**

```
echo $_POST['Nombre'];
echo $_POST['Apellido'];
```

---

Resultado

Jose GArcia