# PHP imprimir Valor de Select segun variable

Tags: php, sql, formularios

Ya muestro en mi tabla los valores de mi base de datos correctamente pero me gustaría que si seleciono la opción con el **id = 1** muestre la información con un echo relacionada a esa información, algo asi es mi código:

```
    <?PHP
//esto es un ejemplo , la información funciona 
//correctamente y trate de no saturar con código de mas
     $id = el numero id de usuario;
     $telefono = el teléfono del usuario
    ?>
```

Aquí esta mi select

```
<select>
//** aqui ya tengo que el $id corresponda al usuario **
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="<?PHP echo $id; ?>">Pablo</option>     //id =1
  <option value="<?PHP echo $id; ?>">Diego</option>     //id =2
</select>
```

Seguido de mi **select** me gustaría mostrar un mensaje según la opción que elija

```
<?php
if ($id == '1') { echo 'el telefono de Pablo es :' . $telefono; }
if ($id == '2') { echo 'el telefono de Diego es :' . $telefono; }
else{ echo 'aqui no se muestra nada'; }  ?>
```

Comment: Esto seria mas facil si lo hicieras en javascript.

Comment: hola alanfcm, tendrias un ejemplo donde pudiese ahcer eso? la verdad javascript noes mi fuerte

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax, parecido a esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166736/ajax-no-envia-el-valor-del-dato-a-php/166737#166737

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso ya no es parte de PHP. La manipulación del **DOM** puedes hacerla con Javascript o con la librería **Jquery**, pero, si lo que quieres es mostrar según tu resultado de tu consulta y poder elegir la opción en el SELECT, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Traer el dato de quién es la opción seleccionada y mediante la validación en cada una de la opciones imprimir "Selected".

```
 <select>
  <option value="">----Elige----</option>
  <option value="1" <?php if($myselect==1){echo "Selected";}?>>juan</option>
  <option value="2" <?php if($myselect==2){echo "Selected";}?>>pablo</option>
  <option value="3" <?php if($myselect==3){echo "Selected";}?>>pedro</option>
  <option value="4" <?php if($myselect==4){echo "Selected";}?>>maria</option>
  </select>
```

ahora bien, como te dije **jquery** / javascript es lo ideal para manipular el **DOM** ya sea que lo quieras o no lo vas a tener que inplementar por obligacion y mas tratandose de php mira que sencillo es usar javascript/**Jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#myselect").change(function(){//obtener valor del select en el evento on change
   
      alert($(this).val())//mostrar el valor en un alert de el select
   
   })

})
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
  <option disabled >select nombre</option>
  <option value="pedro">select</option>
  <option value="pablo">Pablo</option>
  <option value="diego">Diego</option>  
</select>



 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

espero te sirva de algo mi ejemplo  Saludos!

Comment: me estava rompiendo la cabeza con elejemplo anterior ,tuejemplose ve mas dijerible en cuantotermine de adaptarlo a mi codigo te comento,de antemano muchas gracias :D

Comment: un placer ayudar saludos!!

Comment: quedo muy bien muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar:

```
<select name="directorio">
//** aqui ya tengo que el $id corresponda al usuario **
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="<?PHP echo $id.'|'.$telefono; ?>">Pablo</option>     //id =1
  <option value="<?PHP echo $id.'|'.$telefono; ?>">Diego</option>     //id =2
</select>
```

Y del lado php debes usar:

```
$arr_data = explode('|',$_POST['directorio']);
$id = $arr_data[0];
$telefono = $arr_data[1];
if ($id == '1') { echo 'el telefono de Pablo es :' . $telefono; }
if ($id == '2') { echo 'el telefono de Diego es :' . $telefono; }
```